# Combobox selecteditem to be binded in datagrid in silverlight mvvm

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, mvvm

I have one doubt.
The concept is this.
I done one Silverlight application with MVVM architecture.
in that design page i have  the following.
one combobox and one datagrid.
i bind the datagrid using observablecollection and the Employee fields are Fname, Sname,Dept.
I bind the department in combobox. if i choose any of the dept, the datagrid need to be changed based on the department value.
But its not updating. I used linq query to fetch the results. it fetches the value.
But its not binding.
my code is,(In ViewModel)

```
Employees = Silverlight_MVVM.DataHelper.EmployeeDataHelper.EmployeeData();

             var semp = from s in Employees where s.Dept.Equals(Names.Dept) select s;
```

If u know the answer or method plz tell.

i need to assign the selected values in linq "semp" to Datagrid in View.

Answer (score 0):

Hai i found the solution..

```
 2 things to be happened here..
```

1) I have all the fetched data results in Employees. So if i have select any value from combobox i need to bind the selected result in the datagrid. In order to do that we need to clear the Employees using Employees.Clear() method. After that using Foreach loop to access the "semp" and return the value..

2) Now the Employees Contains only one combobox selected value.So Datagrid and ComboBox shows only one value. How to overcome that..
The Result is as follows.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding disemp}"  DisplayMemberPath="Dept" SelectedItem="{Binding Names, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="130,117,0,0" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <si:CallDataMethod Method="BindNew"/>
                    <si:SetProperty TargetName="LayoutRoot"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                    <si:CallDataMethod Method="Selnew"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        </ComboBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public IList<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }
public ObservableCollection<Employee> disemp { get; private set; }
public ObservableCollection<Employee> dgrids { get; private set; }
public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeCopy{ get; private set; }
public EmployeeListViewModel()
        {
            Employees = Silverlight_MVVM.DataHelper.EmployeeDataHelper.EmployeeData ();
            disemp = Silverlight_MVVM.DataHelper.EmployeeDataHelper.Employeedist();
            dgrids=Silverlight_MVVM.DataHelper.EmployeeDataHelper.dgrid();

        }
public void BindNew()
          {
                  Employee emplo = new Employee();
                  Employees = Silverlight_MVVM.DataHelper.EmployeeDataHelper.EmployeeData();
                  EmployeeCopy = dgrids.ToList ();
                  string name = Names.Dept.ToString();
                  var semp = from emp in EmployeeCopy where emp.Dept.Equals(name) select emp;
                  List<Employee> lt = new List<Employee>();
                  lt = semp.ToList();
                  lt.Count();
                  //int i;
                  Employees.Clear();
                  for (int i = 0; i < lt.Count(); i++)
                  {
                      emplo.Fname = lt[0].Fname.ToString();
                      emplo.Sname = lt[0].Sname.ToString();
                      emplo.Dept = lt[0].Dept.ToString();
                      Employees.Add(emplo);
                  }
                  RaisePropertyChanged("Employees");
              }
       }
```

I add dummy ObservableCollections.. Thats all..
Problem Solved..